# Application name in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am connecting to an Oracle Database Server using a SessionPool from cx_Oracle. When I look at the description of the opened session in the Oracle developer, I see that its name is "python.exe". How can I set the application/module name in cx_oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to physically rename python.exe but there is no programmatic way to change what is shown in Oracle Database as the executable.

You can set the driver name by calling [`cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client).  This changes the CLIENT_DRIVER column of V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO.

Other settable attributes including 'module' (which in Oracle terminology is not the program name) are shown in the documentation [Oracle Database End-to-End Tracing](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html#oracle-database-end-to-end-tracing).

```
# Set the tracing metadata
connection.client_identifier = "pythonuser"
connection.action = "Query Session tracing parameters"
connection.module = "End-to-end Demo"

for row in cursor.execute("""
        SELECT username, client_identifier, module, action
        FROM V$SESSION
        WHERE username = 'SYSTEM'"""):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this should help.